# Express.js req.body.undefined?

Tags: mysql, angular, express

Estoy tratando de guardar lo datos que envio del Frontend implementado con Angular y al tratar de actualizar un registro con `this.http.put(this.URL_API +`/${id}`)` y el req.body.name en mi backend me da undefined.Sin embargo al hacer lo mismo pero desde postman si me actualiza el registro y gurda los datos corectamente.Desde mi App CRUD los metodos post,get,delete funcionan y los datos del req.bady llegan al backend.Solo tengo problemas en el metodo put.

Codificando el preceso:
1-Llamada de metodo editar zona desde el boton de la interfaz

```
<td>
 <button (click)="editZona(arrayZona)"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Editar</button>  </td>
```

2-Llamada para seleccionar la zona que voy a actualiza.

```
editZona(pZona: Zona) {
    this.zonaService.seleccionarZona = pZona;
  }
```

3-Llamada al metodo put desde mi metodo post ya que uso el mismo boton para gusrdar los datos en mi Base de Datos

```
 addZona(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.idZona != null && form.value.idZona != "") {   
      this.zonaService.putZona(form.value)
      this.obtZona();
      form.reset();
    }
    else {
      this.zonaService.postZona(form.value);
      this.obtZona();
      form.reset();
    }
    this.obtZona();
    form.reset();
  }
```

4-Metodo

```
  putZona(pZona: Zona) {
    const subsZona = this.http.put(this.URL_API + `/${pZona.idZona}`, `/${pZona.nameZona}`,
    { headers: new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'})}).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
        return subsZona;
      }
```

5-En el Backend

```
zonaCtrl.updateZona = async (req, res) => {
    const Hoy = new Date();
    const zonaId = req.params.id;
    const { id } = req.params.id;
    const nameZ= await Zona.findByPk(zonaId);
    const zonaUpdate = {
        nameZona: req.body.nameZona ,//LLEGA VACIO O undefined eL req.body ?????  
        updatedAt : Hoy
    }
    await Zona.update(zonaUpdate, { where: { idZona: zonaId } });
    res.json({
        status: "Zona Actualizada",
    })
};
```

Comment: Considera incluir tu codigo para contextualizar mejor a la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre solucion en mi codigo.

```
  putZona(pZona: Zona) {
    const subsZona = this.http.put(this.URL_API + `/${pZona.idZona}`, pZona).subscribe(res => {
      this.getZona();
    });
    return subsZona;
  }
```

Nota:En la llamada al metodo put en el metodo errononeo no le pasaba el parametro pZona como instancia de la clase zona. Sino que le pasaba el atributo nameZona.Y el metodo put tiene como parametro`(url,body,options)`.Gracias a los que trataron de ayudar.